# Mostrar valores de un combobox

Tags: javascript, c#, ext.net

Tengo el código de tal forma que me muestra un valor del combobox, pero necesito que me muestre todos. ¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Os adjunto código, no sé si me faltará algo más por adjuntar.

```
  <ext:Store ID="stAutopistas" runat="server" RemoteSort="true" AutoLoad="False">
    <Proxy>
        <ext:AjaxProxy Url="/GO/Autopista/GetComboPorGerenciaLista">
            <ActionMethods Read="GET" />
            <Reader>
                <ext:JsonReader IDProperty="Id" Root="data" TotalProperty="total" />
            </Reader>
        </ext:AjaxProxy>
    </Proxy>
    <Model>
        <ext:Model runat="server">
            <Fields>
                <ext:ModelField Name="Id" Type="Int" />
                <ext:ModelField Name="Name" />
            </Fields>
        </ext:Model>
    </Model>
    <Sorters>
        <ext:DataSorter Property="Name" />
    </Sorters>
    <Listeners>
        <BeforeLoad Handler="#{stAutopistas}.getProxy().setExtraParam('pGerenciaId',#{cmbGerenciaId}.getValue())" />
        <Exception Handler="Ext.net.Notification.show({iconCls: 'icon-exclamation', html: response.message || response.statusText, title: 'EXCEPTION', hideDelay: 5000});" />
    </Listeners>



  public List<ComboEstandarViewModel> GetComboPorGerenciaLista(Gerencia gerencia)
    {
        List<ComboEstandarViewModel> retorno = null;

        try
        {
            retorno = Database.Gerencias.Where(_ => _.Id == gerencia.Id && _.FechaBaja == null).Select(aa => aa.Autopistas.Where(a => a.FechaBaja == null))
                .SelectMany(ll => ll.Select(a => new ComboEstandarViewModel { Id = a.Id.ToString(), Name = a.Nombre + " - " + a.Gerencia.Nombre }))
                .ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dominio.Log.Instance.AgregarError(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex, "");
        }

        return retorno;
    }
```

El problema es que solo me da el primero de la lista, pero no me da todos, necesito crear una lista, pero no se 100% como hacerlo..

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que seria ext.net? por lo que veo, javascript  no tiene nada que ver con esta pregunta.

Comment: creo que esta algo retorcido ese linq que armas con los metodos de extension, usas un where, luego un where dentro de un select, despues un selectmany, porque tan complejo ?

Answer (score 1):

Una cadena de llamadas LinQ trabaja sobre el mismo conjunto de datos, así que toda tu cadena trabaja sobre lo que sea que es `Gerencias`:

```
Database.Gerencias.Where
//       ~~~~~~~~~ <--- Colección de datos sobre la que se opera.
                  (
                      _ => _.Id == gerencia.Id && _.FechaBaja == null
                  )
                  .Select
                  (
                      aa => aa.Autopistas.Where
                      (
                          a => a.FechaBaja == null
                      )
                  )
                  .SelectMany
                  (
                      ll => ll.Select
                      (
                          a => new ComboEstandarViewModel { Id = a.Id.ToString(), Name = a.Nombre + " - " + a.Gerencia.Nombre }
                      )
                  )
                  .ToList();
```

Por lo que deduzco de tu código, el objeto "*Gerencia*" debe parecerse a:

```
class Autopista
{
    public DateTime FechaBaja { get; set; }
}

class Gerencia
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaBaja { get; set; }
    public List<Autopista> Autopistas = new List<Autopista>();
}
```

Lo ideal sería que en lugar de adivinar qué tipos estás usando: los mostrases. Ahora vamos a analizar cada parte.

- [LinQ Where](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where): Filtra una colección de valores en base a una condición. El resultado será una secuencia `Enumerable` con los valores que cumplan la condición.
- [LinQ Select](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select): Transforma una colección de valores en una secuencia `Enumerable` de otro tipo.
- [LinQ SelectMany](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany): Transforma una secuencia de secuencias en una secuencia de elementos.

Así que tu cadena LinQ lo que hace es:

1. Selecciona una colección de Gerencias.
2. Transforma las Gerencias en colecciones de Autopistas (contenidas en las Gerencias).
3. Transforma las colecciones de Autopistas en una colección de `ComboEstandarViewModel`.

Si siguiendo esta cadena te quedas con un elemento será porque de todas las Gerencias cuyo `Id` coincide con el facilitado como argumento sólo una tiene Autopistas y la que tiene Autopistas sólo tiene una. Por cierto, tu cadena LinQ puede ser escrita de otra forma:

```
Database.Gerencias.Where
                  (
                      /* Gerencias cuyo Id sea el facilitado como argumento
                         y no tengan fecha de baja */
                      g => g.Id == gerencia.Id && g.FechaBaja == null
                  )
                  .SelectMany
                  (
                      // Nos quedamos con las autopistas
                      g => g.Autopistas
                  )
                  .Where
                  (
                      // Sólo autopistas sin fecha de baja
                      a => a.FechaBaja == null
                  )
                  .Select
                  (
                      // En forma de ComboEstandarViewModel
                      a => new ComboEstandarViewModel { Id = a.Id.ToString(), Name = a.Nombre + " - " + a.Gerencia.Nombre }
                  )
                  .ToList();
```